# How to generate SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) to create database tables and fields. I have 100's of tables in a single database. Now I need to make the same on few more servers.

I feel it's too hard to write SQL queries to create that database. Is there any reverse process to generate an SQL query file from phpMyAdmin or anyother tool? I want to create a database in a GUI, and I need the SQL query for my database. Is there any tool to generate it automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to export a database (with many tables) using phpMyAdmin, and then import it and use it on another server.

Yes. You can do that.

Select the database on the left-hand side in phpMyAdmin and then: 
*Export* -> *Select All Tables* -> *Adjust Options* -> *Go*.

You are going to get <youdatabasename>.sql file, with all the table definitions inside. Then you can import it in another phpMyAdmin or other database handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to do this. Then [`--nodata`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) switch should do what you want.